# Transform reST list item for rst2html output

Tags: transform, docutils, rst2html.py

I have a reStructuredText document with todo list items:

```
Vim
===

- ✓ (2021-11-05) RST Section text object
  (drop it in favor of env text object)

  Probably should be based on the output of ``:Toc`` command to properly
  identify all sub sections if this is needed.

- ✓ (2021-11-05) RST "Environment" text object
```

Which could be setup in vim to have nicely colored unicode checkmark and (date)

[image]

Regular `rst2html.py` knows nothing about those checkmarks and dates, but it looks like it is possible to use `Transform` feature of docutils to add css classes to those list items.

Probably documentation of the docutils is written for the more experienced people, but I could not find an easy guide on how to:

1. create your own `Transform`
2. apply it to your reStructuredText document.

PS, I could get the structure of the document with `rst2pseudoxml.py` and I can see elements I should change:

```
            <bullet_list bullet="-">
                <list_item>
                    <paragraph>
                        вњ“ (2021-11-05) RST Section text object
                        (drop it in favor of env text object)
```

But have no clue where to start from.

Comment: Unfortunately, Transforms are the least documented part of Docutils. Transforms are created by subclassing `docutils.transform.Transform`. See for example "docutils/transforms/writer_aux.py". Currently, adding custom transforms to the processing pipe requires subclassing a docutils component (reader, parser, writer, ...) and adding the new transfrom re-defining the `get_transforms()` method. See "docutils/parsers/rst/__init__.py" for an example adding the `SmartQuotes` transform.

Comment: [Docutils TODO lists](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/todo-lists.html) explores several alternatives to mark up and style TODO lists with CSS. Maybe, together with its [source](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/todo-lists.txt), it can help solving your problem without resorting to defining a custom parser and transition.